# If a div starts with display: none the library does not work. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently using the library:

It works fine, but if it starts hidden it does not work well. But I strictly need it to start hidden.
I have a div with id "div_swiper" that contains the swiper. Initially has the "ng-hide" class, if I execute this, without this class, if it works fine. Like I said, I need this div to start hidden.
[image]

How can I make it start by being hidden and working normally?

```
  <div id="div_swiper" class='ng-hide'>
    <swiper>
      <slides>
        <slide>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla porro esse quia, voluptas, doloribus est modi quibusdam provident in deleniti, fuga nisi odit quod incidunt a saepe aliquam cupiditate veniam.</slide>
        <slide>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit consequatur amet eius adipisci. Sunt quod fuga ipsa, maiores, vel expedita iste commodi, harum laboriosam voluptatum, consectetur cupiditate dicta impedit nobis.</slide>
      </slides>
      <pagination></pagination>
    </swiper>
  </div>

  $scope.hide=function(){
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div_swiper' ) );
      //myEl[0].style.display="none";
      myEl.removeClass('ng-show');
      myEl.addClass('ng-hide');
  }
  $scope.show=function(){
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div_swiper' ) );
      //myEl[0].style.display="inline-block";
      myEl.removeClass('ng-hide');
      myEl.addClass('ng-show');
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtha0wbe/

Comment: You want `#div_swipper` to appears on your controller load ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN The only thing I want, is when I click the show button, the library works normally like this would, if from the beginning it does not have the class ng-hide

Answer (score 0):

There is no  need to be mucking about directly in the DOM like that.  Not only is it more complicated than necessary, you're inviting collisions between components by depending on global IDs.

Use scope variables and let Angular do the work:

Template:

```
  <div id="div_swiper" ng-cloak ng-if='{hidden: isHidden}'>
    <swiper>
      <slides>
        <slide>...</slide>
        <slide>...</slide>
      </slides>
      <pagination></pagination>
    </swiper>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {opacity: 0; position:absolute; pointer-events:none} /* see below */
```

Component code:

```
  $scope.isHidden = true;
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $scope.isHidden = true;
  }
  $scope.show = function() {
    $scope.isHidden = false;
  }
```

Update to your fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/n8cd3orp/  (Note however that this code would better be put in a directive than a controller, as a controller will share scope values across all directives using it; directives will keep it local to each directive.)

NOTE on the CSS: The ui-slider component you're using depends on testing the panel visibility (or possibly its dimensions, which are inaccessible on hidden elements) to decide where to put those little dots at the bottom.  Hiding it via `opacity` instead of `display` allows that to work properly.

Alternatively, you could skip "hiding" it altogether, and simply not include it in the DOM until it needs to be visible:

```
 <div id="div_swiper" ng-cloak ng-if='!isHidden'>
```

Comment: Does not work, the behavior remains the same. Look at the difference starting, without the ng-hide class.

Comment: Do you mean the little flicker of visibility that occurs before the directive compiles? You can prevent that using ng-cloak (Added to example and fiddle).

Comment: The behavior is different if the div starts to be hidden from the beginning.

Comment: Ah, now I  understand  -- looks like you've uncovered a bug in that ui-swiper component (it must be checking the pane visibility to determine when to display the little dots at the bottom, so fails to work when the component is hidden during init).   Give me a moment, I may have a workaround but need to test it first...

Comment: @yavg Yep: the simple workaround works; see updated answer.  Thanks for the screenshot; it wasn't clear from your initial description what the problem you were trying to solve was.

Comment: You avoided, put the display: none, and you used opacity. It was not necessary to use ng-cloack. Why did you add the position: absolute?
This works. I would have loved to know how to fix the display: none

Comment: I added ng-cloak because I initially thought the problem you were trying to solve was the flicker of visible template before the component compiles.  The `position:absolute` is needed because otherwise the zero-opacity element still takes up space in the document (try removing it, you'll see what I mean.)  Same thing for the `pointer-events:none`: elements with zero opacity still catch mouse clicks unless you tell the browser not to.  (Alternatively you could just position the element offscreen while "hidden.)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use "display:none" short of rewriting ui-slider itself.  (All that said, a cleaner solution would be to simply not instantiate the component until it's needed in the first place -- i.e. only insert it into the DOM when the user first clicks "show".) I've added an example of how to do that in the answer.